# Error creating Table in Excel Destination in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, precision

I have a problem with data conversion in SSIS. I have a SQL Table that have a column with a field with decimal data type.
I need create a Report in Excel and in SSIS when I create the table in Excel Destination I receive this message "Invalid precision for decimal data type. (Microsoft Access Database Engine)".
The field in Excel is NUMERIC (11,2). I thinked that the number 2 was decimal numbers but I red that is the scale. 11,2 are the decimal format data type that I have in SQL.
How can I solve my problem?
Thanks to all

Giorgio

Comment: try by setting DelayValidationProperty of data flow task to TRUE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have same error

Comment: Please update your question with the snapshots of Excel Destination Editor, table schema etc. It will give clear picture related to the problem.

Comment: add a package screenshot to your question. it will be more clear

Comment: check Is there any column with decimal datatype like decimal of 38,6 which excel doesn't support if you find any column with decimal reduce this half exactly which means decimal(19,6)